# Features of logging tools in Salesforce

Tags: apex, logging

What logging tools do you use in Salesforce, and what features do they offer? Such as:

- **Loggly**: https://www.loggly.com/
- **Splunk** Cloud 'https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1931/'